# Use the current namespace with pars_args() in the argparse package in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I am using the `argparse` module in Python3. The result of the parsed arguments are given back as a `Namespace` object. But I want to have them in the current namespace and not a different one.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='desc')
parser.add_argument('--profile', dest='profile_name', help='help')

# I need the magic here    
print( parser.parse_args(namespace=self) )
print(profile_name)
```

Is there a way to handle this?
Or do I have to make it myself manually like this:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
profile_name = args.profile_name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be confusing 2 uses of 'namespace'.

One `namespace` is the dictionary that holds the variables of this module or function.

`parser.parse_args()` creates an `argparse.Namespace` object, and puts its values in it, using `setattr`. This class definition is pretty simple.

`parser.parse_args(namespace=myNamespace)` should work with any object that accepts the `setattr`, `getattr` and `hasattr` methods.  A dictionary does not work.

If given a dictionary the first error I get is in

```
setattr(namespace, action.dest, default)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'checked'
```

---

Are you asking this because you want to put the `argparse` attributes directly in the local namespace dictionary?

You can convert a Namespace to a dictionary with `vars(args)`.  And you can add those items to another dictionary with `update` (e.g. `locals().update(vars(args))` ).

Or if you have a function that takes `**kwargs`, you could use: `foo(**vars(args))` to put those arguments into the function's namespace. This does a better job of localizing the change.  It also lets you define the variables with the normal keyword syntax.

Answer (score 1):

**I do not recommend this** since it can override previously defined variables, especially if all you want is avoid typing a couple of characters, but you can add variables to the **global** scope like this:

```
args = parser.parse_args()

for k, v in args.__dict__.items():
    globals()[k] = v
print(profile_name)
```